# SQL Server Configuration Manager express 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to enable TCP/IP on my SQL Server Express 2012 but I cannot find SQL Server Configuration Manager. I have windows 8 and I made a search for "SQL Server Configuration Manager" but nothing comes up.

Do I have to install SQL Server Configuration Manager separately or does it come with SQL Server? If it comes within it, how do I start it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As is [stated on My Tec Bits](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/sql-server-2012-configuration-manager-in-windows-8):

If you have installed SQL Server 2012 on windows 8, you may not see the Configuration manager in the app list. SQL Server 2012 configuration manager is not a stand alone program. it is a snap-in for MMC (Microsoft Management Console). Follow the below steps in Windows 8 to open the Configuration Manager of SQL Server 2012 or
2008.

1. Go to Windows 8 Start screen.
2. Start typing in SQLServerManager11.msc if you are looking for SQL
   Server 2012 configuration manager. Type in SQLServerManager10.msc if
   you are looking for SQL Server 2008 configuration manager.
3. In the result panel you can see the SQLServerConfiguration Manager.
4. Click the icon to launch the SQL Server Configuration manager.
5. The configuration manager will open in MMC.

Comment: `SQLServerManager13.msc` for 2016. You won't get it to pop up until you type the full name. For future editions, try incrementing the number until you find it.